# Laravel Policy to limit Filament Bulk Delete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

In my Laravel project, I try to limit delete action. Non-admin users should be able to delete only their own content.

```
public function forceDelete(User $user, Slider $slider): bool
{
    return $user->hasRole("Admin") || $slider->created_by === $user->id;
}
```

I can still see the bulk delete action select and I can still delete the content I didn't create.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: try this for bulk `public function bulkForceDelete(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasRole("Admin");
    }`

Comment: @IshtiaqAhmed There's no `bulkForceDelete` in the Filament documentation nor in the codebase. Where are you getting this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, all the built-in bulk actions suffer from this issue.

https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/getting-started#authorization

> Filament uses the `forceDeleteAny()` method because iterating through multiple records and checking the `forceDelete()` policy is not very performant.

In our case, we made a custom action (extended off `Filament\Tables\Actions\BulkAction`) that *does* iterate through all the items.